# True or False? There is a non-invertible matrix $B$ such that $B^4- I_4 - B^2=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have no idea how to answer this question, I tried starting with a matrix $B$ containing $16$ different variables but the calculations took hours and I don't think I was getting anywhere anyway.
This is a question from a homework for an introductory module on Matrices and Vectors.

Comment: You are indeed not meant to solve this the "hard way". There are a few theoretical results about matrix polynomials. Do you know any? Does, for instance, Cayley-Hamilton ring a bell?

Comment: What is $I_4$?  Is that a 4 by 4 identity matrix?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Tell us what you have tried and in what context this came up: A Linear Algebra class? What is the current topic of the class?

Comment: @Arthur We haven't studied results about matrix polynomials, or matrix polynomials at all for that matter... We have studied all the basics on matrices and vectors up as far as subspaces and all that jazz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$ B\cdot(B^3-B)=I$$

Comment: Nice.  Does factoring out another $B$ help?

Comment: It's not necessary. This equation implies that $B$ is invertible with inverse $B^3 - B$, so we're already done, since the question specified $B$ non-invertible.

Comment: @mjw Not really.

Comment: I feel like a bit of a fool now that seems quite obvious... Thanks very much, sorry for bothering with such a simple one

Comment: Right!   Got it, thanks!